# calling UIview methdods

Tags: iphone, uiview

I want to call this method in a user defined function

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

Is it possible ?? if yes,How ?? Pl. guide me.

Answer (score 1):

This method should be implemented for a [custom UIView**Controller**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW23), for instance

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
   ...
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)io;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)io {
  return io != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}
@end
```

Comment: but how to call this Function in .m file ? If we do by [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation] then we are required to pass arguement . What arguement should be passed bcoz it is of UIInterfaceOrienttion type ?